# Is there a way to stream your webcam to your android app using Webrtc?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webrtc

Is there a way to stream your webcam to your android app using Webrtc?

Comment: yes, there is, please look for tutorials, before asking on stack overflow

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @FinnLyonn can you share a link for it because i found webrtc video calling not (pc webcam stream viewing on android app) thanku.

Comment: @Cem i want to display laptop's webcam live stream to my android app

Comment: @Daniyal Have you had any success?

Comment: @CanniZarro unfortunately i used raspberry pi which generated live stream returning an ip address which i used in react native webview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the main concept should be:

1. Use socket.io for Realtime communication between clients. https://socket.io/
2. Use peerJS to wrap webRTC on the browser. https://peerjs.com/

Of course Node.js, and express should be part of the development too.

You should find many tutorials on the web for this.

Comment: Sir actually i am not so aware of using these libraries so can you share a link where i can see the tutorial for my requirement, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did an app that uses WebRTC for screen sharing

My work is based on this [repo](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC), please take a look

Comment: Thanks sir i ran your repo as clone using 'npm start' now i am confused how to run the repo given in https://github.com/Jeffiano/ScreenShareRTC for android?

Comment: Which part? that repo has some instructions on readme file. Best way to test it out is using android studio and change the host value of this file "res/values/strings.xml"

Comment: one command prompt is running the https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC file? how should i run the files on github.com/Jeffiano/ScreenShareRTC  to recieve thecamera  stream on android application?